# Popup window not resizing? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I'm using a very simple form launched from a CRM system that opens up an IE 8 page but even with resizeable=yes it's not allowing me to resize?

Is there anything that I'm missing or is it just down to the fact that it's not 100% working due to it being launched from our CRM system?

```
<form action="http://intranet-srv02/reports/selecttag.php" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<input name="userid" type="hidden" value="2" />
<input type="submit" value="DO NOT USE - TEST" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function target_popup(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=1200,height=750,resizeable=yes,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "resizable" and not "resizeable"

use this:

```
function target_popup(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=1200,height=750,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
```